# htaccess: Rewrite second part of url having "view_retailer" to "view-retailer"

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to change url from

```
http://www.dev.example.in/view_retailer/ebay-in
```

to

```
http://www.dev.example.in/view-retailer/ebay-in
```

Here is my rules, and these rules are not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view-retailer/(.*)$ /view_retailer/$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

There are many urls which are having **"view_retailer"** in common, and I want to rename them to **"view-retailer"**.
Can anyone please help me out to rename the url from 
http://www.dev.example.in/view_retailer/ebay-in to  http://www.dev.example.in/view-retailer/ebay-in

I have tried to re-write url in http://htaccess.mwl.be/, please have a look on the following image

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know the answer.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @Starkeen: I have updated the question, Rules are not working to rename the url from  http://www.dev.example.in/view_retailer/ebay-in to http://www.dev.example.in/view-retailer/ebay-in

Comment: You are already using a Rule, isnt that working?

Comment: @Starkeen: No, I also tried out on http://htaccess.mwl.be/ , but still does not work. please have a look on the image i have uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to my question.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view_retailer/(.*)/$ /view-retailer/(.*)/ [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule view_retailer/(.*) http://www.example.in/view-retailer/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Here is the following code tested and running on http://htaccess.mwl.be/

[image]